# Is there a better way to copy images from a repo in mvn?

Tags: git, maven

I've googled a bunch, and I came up with a "solution" to my problem, but it doesn't scale, and there has to be a better way.

I have an app that needs a bunch of images, and I don't want to put them into my git repo.  I've pushed my images into an artifact repo, and I added a chunk like this to my pom:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>com.company.product.images</groupId>
            <artifactId>dotted_gray_line</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <type>gif</type>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/layout/images</outputDirectory>
          </artifactItem>

          ... bunches more exactly like this except for the artifactId ...

        </artifactItems>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>compile</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

I'd like to have a way to copy all of my images over in one piece.  For this application there's a dozen images, I can manage this, but I have another app with hundreds of images.  It will take up 90% of the pom.

Is there a plugin that does this?  Do I have to roll my own by creating a zip and writing a mvn plugin to grab the zip then unzip it?

Am I going about this in the entirely wrong direction?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The [maven-dependency-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) can unpack zip/jar files...so best approach is to create a jar/zip from all those images and use that zipo/jar file instead...

Comment: @khmarbaise, thank you, that worked for me.